# Strange artefact appearing in my HTML in Chrome/Webkit (with screenshots and live example)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm a bit puzzled by this strange artefact being left in my HTML - here's a very zoomed-in screenshot:

[image: Strange HTML artefact]

I circled it in red - it's this strange small line. But I cannot track down where on earth it's coming from.

I have a section of the code on JSFiddle to reproduce the bug - can anyone work out where it's coming from and how I can get rid of it? Here's the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xfmV9/

I'm using Google Chrome Dev, but the problem doesn't seem to appear in Firefox...

Thanks!

Comment: I've removed my answer due to the user experience problem it contained. The extra complexity required to fix it isn't worth it - just remove the whitespace :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be an underline from a space within your anchor tag?  Try stripping the white space (newline and spaces) within your anchor tag.

As in this new Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/g2G7P/

Answer (score 1):

it's just an space inside your `<a>` after the `<img>`

check this http://jsfiddle.net/xfmV9/2/